# How to fix public route in react router v6 showing the login for a spli second

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a problem with public and private route. In which when the user is already authenticated the private and public routes work. But for some reason when I refresh to the homepage it shows the login page for a split second.

How do i fix this?

**PRIVATE ROUTE**

```
const PrivateRoute = () => {
  const auth = useAuth();

  if (!auth.user) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" />;
  }

  return <Outlet />;
};
```

**PUBLIC ROUTE**

```
const PublicRoute = () => {
  const auth = useAuth();
  if (auth.user) {
    return <Navigate to="/" />;
  }

  return <Outlet />;
};
```

**APP**

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<PublicRoute />}>
    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
    <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
  </Route>
  <Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/message" element={<Message />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should ensure that your "unauthenticated" state value doesn't match the "I don't know the authentication status" state value. What this means for example, if `auth.user` being `true` or some defined user object equals a user being considered "authenticated" and if a `auth.user` being `false` or `null` equals a user being considered "unauthenticated" then you shouldn't use an initial `auth.user` that is either `true`|`<user object>` or `false`|`null`.

In other words you want to use some indeterminant value to indicate the authentication status has yet to be determined, and in this indeterminant state you can render `null` or some loading indicator until the authentication status resolves.

You tagged with firebase so I'll be assuming that somewhere in your code is an `onAuthStateChanged` call that returns either the user object or `null` when there is no authenticated user. In this case the `user` comparison will be against `undefined`. Just ensure that the default `auth.user` value is `undefined`.

Assuming something similar:

```
export default function useAuth() {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState({}); // user undefined

  const user = useFirebase();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(
      user.auth,
      (user) => setAuth({
        user: user ?? false
      })
    );

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [user]);

  return auth;
}
```

Example:

```
const PrivateRoute = () => {
  const auth = useAuth();

  if (auth?.user === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return auth.user
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
};

const PublicRoute = () => {
  const auth = useAuth();

  if (auth?.user === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return auth.user
    ? <Navigate to="/" replace />
    : <Outlet />;
};
```

Comment: omg thank you so much! i been searching for this problem for weeks and you explain it really good even though i forgot to add my code on firebase. Thanks man!